# Get numbers from EditText

Tags: java, android, string, android-edittext, int

I know that his have been asked a few times, but I have been trying everything I have found with no luck. I'm still having a error. Here's my code.

xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Write item value."
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:textSize="25dp" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="202dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Value"
    android:inputType="number" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>
```

java

```
public class PopupValores extends Activity {

    EditText valor1;
    String myEditValue;
    public static int valor;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.popupvalores);

        valor1 = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.editText1);
        myEditValue = valor1.getText().toString();
        valor = Integer.parseInt(myEditValue);   <<<<Line 20

    }
}
```

LogCat

```
05-08 21:02:10.023: W/dalvikvm(6074): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40020578)
05-08 21:02:10.039: E/AndroidRuntime(6074): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-08 21:02:10.039: E/AndroidRuntime(6074): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.dc.maker/com.dc.maker.PopupValores}: java.lang.NumberFormatException: unable to parse '' as integer
05-08 21:02:10.039: E/AndroidRuntime(6074):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1651)
05-08 21:02:10.039: E/AndroidRuntime(6074):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
05-08 21:02:10.039: E/AndroidRuntime(6074):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
05-08 21:02:10.039: E/AndroidRuntime(6074):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
05-08 21:02:10.039: E/AndroidRuntime(6074):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-08 21:02:10.039: E/AndroidRuntime(6074):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
05-08 21:02:10.039: E/AndroidRuntime(6074):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
05-08 21:02:10.039: E/AndroidRuntime(6074):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-08 21:02:10.039: E/AndroidRuntime(6074):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
05-08 21:02:10.039: E/AndroidRuntime(6074):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
05-08 21:02:10.039: E/AndroidRuntime(6074):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
05-08 21:02:10.039: E/AndroidRuntime(6074):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-08 21:02:10.039: E/AndroidRuntime(6074): Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: unable to parse '' as integer
05-08 21:02:10.039: E/AndroidRuntime(6074):     at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:362)
05-08 21:02:10.039: E/AndroidRuntime(6074):     at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:332)
05-08 21:02:10.039: E/AndroidRuntime(6074):     at com.popupclass.PopupValores.onCreate(PopupValores.java:20)
05-08 21:02:10.039: E/AndroidRuntime(6074):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
05-08 21:02:10.039: E/AndroidRuntime(6074):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1615)
05-08 21:02:10.039: E/AndroidRuntime(6074):     ... 11 more
```

I'm trying to get a int from the EditText and then use it in other class to determinate a value of something. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Are you getting an error, if so please post the logcat trace.  If not what is the value of `valor`? (Ha, that's ironic.)

Comment: lol yes it is, LogCat added. EDIT: valor should be the value of the number writed by the user in EditText

Comment: I'm gettint 0 no matter what I write on the EditText, why is that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The exception is:

```
Java.lang.NumberFormatException: unable to parse '' as integer
```

And it's only because there is no value in the editbox1 field.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.popupvalores);

    valor1 = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.editText1);
    myEditValue = valor1.getText().toString();

    Log.debug("logtag", myEditValue); // Here you can see the output.

    try {
        valor = Integer.parseInt(myEditValue); 
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        Log.e("logtag", "Exception: " + e.toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm gettint 0 no matter what I write on the EditText, why is that?

Comment: This code is only triggered when you create the activity. At runtime there is nothing in the EditText. 
Are you only using numbers in the EditBox?

Also, check the string value of myEditValue, perhaps it's something like '1' or something. If that is the case then Integer.parseInt will have trouble parsing it.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to access `valor1` too soon, `valor1` is currently an empty string. You must process the value after to user has had a chance to define something.

Try adding a button like this:

```
(Button) button = (Button) findViewByID(R.id.button1);
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View view) {
        String temp = valor1.getText().toString();
        if(temp.isEmpty() == false) {
            valor = Integer.parseInt(temp);
            Log.v("SO", "Valor = " + valor);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok I will wait for that code, because then I don't know how to do it.

Comment: @Sam, As I remember, `String.isEmpty()` does not exist in Android SDK.

Comment: I appreciate the feedback, but here is [some documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#isEmpty%28%29)

Comment: I'm gettint 0 no matter what I write on the EditText, why is that?

Comment: If you are using the accepted answer, `valor1` is still read _before_ the user has a chance to enter any text. Test it yourself add `android:text="562"` to the EditText's XML, with the accepted answer now the only value you will get is 562... You need to change _when_ you read the user input; like after they push a "Submit" button, after `valor1` loses focus, as you are launching a second activity, etc.

Answer (score 1):

The code is trying to parse an empty string from the EditText '' as an int which causes an exception to be thrown.

Your example code is also missing the closing LinearLayout tag.

Answer (score 1):

**Use regular expression...below:**

```
public class PopupValores extends Activity {

EditText valor1;
String myEditValue;
public static int valor;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.popupvalores);

    valor1 = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.editText1);
    myEditValue = valor1.getText().toString();
    valor = Integer.parseInt(myEditValue.replaceAll("[\\D]",""));

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Your code above will definitely cause problem, because you did `Integer.parseInt(myEditValue)` in `onCreate()`, at the time your Activity is being created, your EditText is not yet filled with any text(and you didn't provide a default value in its XML definition), so it is an empty string, and `Integer.parseInt(emptyString)` will throw `NumberFormatException`.

The correct way to doing this is moving the code parsing the value of EditText to somewhere, where in response to user events, or simply `try...catch` `Integer.parseInt()`.

The safest way is always to `try...catch` `Integer.parseInt()`, because we should **Never Trust user's input**.